# How to remove the zero values in bar chart (achartengine) ?

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

Please take a look at the picture below. How can I make the "0" disappear from the bar chart ?

[image]

Comment: would be helpful to see your xml code! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not add the zero values to the dataset. If you do add them, then don't expect AChartEngine to remove them.